# NavController Logout

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have `NavController`'s inside 3 of my `TabBarController` of my app. When I go to the logout function in my app and logout, which is in `TabBarController` no.2, I made it return to `TabBarController` no.1. However, it does not go back to the root of the NavController of tab 1.

I have referenced the `NavController` in the `appDelegate` just how I did with the `TabBarController` but I could not do what I did with the `TabBarController` with setSelectedIndex.

How can I make my `NavController` go back into the first view?

Thanks.

**Code**

```
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = appDelegate.rootController;
    ProductsNavController *productsNavController = appDelegate.productsNavController;

    [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

This is what I did for the tabBar, can I do something like this for the Nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` as [mentioned in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a)?

After your update, try this:

```
[…]
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
[appDelegate.productsNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: @unset: Can I not do something similar to the code I put above? Thanks.

Comment: @unset: it is working in a way. As it's going back up a level, but not all the way to the start. Is there a way to go all the way to the start? Thanks.

Comment: I've done it mate. `[appDelegate.productsNavController popToViewController:[appDelegate.productsNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];`